# Object literal string escape math sign number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this string `const myVar = '1-2'` I want to do spacing and make the variable to become `'1 - 2'`.

I tried this `${myVar.split("-")[0] - myVar.split("-")[1]}`, and the output I got is -1, because the - sign is being treated as math operator. Any help?

Comment: Of course, because it’s inside the `${}` expression. It’s supposed to be of the form `${`…`} - ${`…`}`. How else is JavaScript going to know the difference between a `-` as a minus or as a literal hyphen?

Comment: `myVar` is const and strings are immutable...

Comment: `${myVar.split('-').join(' - ')}`. shouldn't matter if it's a `const` because it doesn't change the const, it just produces a new variable

Comment: @ASDFGerte `myVar` is neither being reassigned nor mutated.

Comment: @Xufox `make the variable to become '1 - 2'` this is impossible.

Comment: @Jorg—you mean "*…produces a new value*". ;-)

Comment: It's not an "object literal", it's a **template literal**.

Comment: @RobG yes, it’s been a long day :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use .replace(). Just assign this to a new variable, so

```
const myVar = '1-2';
let newVar = myVar.replace("-", " - ");
```

newVar will be the result of myVar with spacing on each side of the hyphen.

Comment: There's no need for another variable, the OP can just fix the template expression.